# how to set background image for navigation bar without covering status bar in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set background image for navigation bar. this is my code:

```swift
navBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "myImage")
navBar.standardAppearance = appearance
navBar.compactAppearance = appearance
navBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

the result is like this:
[image]

but I want to achieve this:
[image]